# jQuery Mobile + backbone.js: navbar issue

Tags: jquery-mobile, backbone.js

I load pages created from templates dynamically with a function from the Router (as seen on some tutorials):

```
    changePage: function(page) { // page is a View object
        $(page.el).attr('data-role', 'page');
        page.render();
        $('body').append($(page.el));
        var transition = $.mobile.defaultPageTransition;
        if (this.firstPage) {
            transition = 'none';
            this.firstPage = false;
        }
        $.mobile.changePage($(page.el), {changeHash:false, transition: transition});
    }
```

The thing is when pages contain a JQ Mobile navbar, the active item is not highlighted. Actually it is, like 1 ms, then it's not, I feel like it's because the navbar is "reloaded".
When I click 2 times on the same item, it works the second time.

Is there anybody who is able to have working navbars with jQuery Mobile and backbone.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing that:

```
var activeTab = null;

$('[data-role=page]').live('pageshow', function (event, ui) { 
    $.each($('[data-role=navbar] ul li').children(), function (i, val) {
        if (typeof activeTab !== "undefined" && activeTab != null && $(val).attr('id') == 'navTab' + activeTab)
            $(val).addClass($.mobile.activeBtnClass);
        else
            $(val).removeClass($.mobile.activeBtnClass);
    });
    activeTab = null;
});
```

And for each route that requires an active tab I just do for instance:

```
r_search: function() { // Search page (form)
    activeTab = "Search";
    this.changePage(new SearchView());
},
```