# Back buttons in jQuery Mobile with Backbone do not work properly

Tags: jquery-mobile, backbone.js

I am using jQueryMobile and Backbone and am having problems with custom or dynamically generated back buttons not going back in the history properly.  I am using the `data-rel="back"` attribute on anchor tags as described in the documentation: http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/dist/demos/widgets/headers/

My back button code is as follows:

```
<a href="#" data-rel="back" data-icon="arrow-l" data-iconpos="notext"></a>
```

When I click the back button it doesn't seem to use the `data-rel="back"` functionality at all and instead goes to the page as specified in the `href` attribute, which in most cases is '#' or empty.

This can be confirmed by hard-coding a different `href` value - the back button will go that page, and not the previous page in the history as it's supposed to.

I suspect it to be a conflict between Backbone and jQuery Mobile and the configurations necessary to get them to work nicely (let Backbone handle page transitions), but do not know how to get around it.

As described in the jQM docs I had to set the following in a `mobile-config` file:

```
$.mobile.ajaxEnabled            = false;
$.mobile.linkBindingEnabled     = false;
$.mobile.hashListeningEnabled   = false;
$.mobile.pushStateEnabled       = false;
$.mobile.changePage.defaults.changeHash = false;
```

**Note:** I've reviewed many of the posts on this subject on SO before posting and there doesn't seem to be a suitable solution presented in any of the responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  It was a combination of implementing the solution found here:
[jQuery Mobile + backbone.js: page transition when going back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11248881/jquery-mobile-backbone-js-page-transition-when-going-back)

AND

adding an attribute 'data-bypass' to all my anchor tags that I wanted to bind custom events to as I was using a piece of code from the Backbone Boilerplate project to handle relative urls.

Comment: You should [accept your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) so that when future visitors see your question they can see that there is an accepted solution.

Answer (score 0):

I got into the same situation and found that a simple solution is to just create a new route and use that to go back in history.

For example, just set the `href` value of your back button to something like `#back`:

```
<a href="#back" data-icon="back" data-rel="back" title="Go back">Back</a>
```

Then add a new route

```
routes: {
    ...   
    'back' : 'back',
    ...
}
```

And in the the code to handle the route, just go two steps back in history.

```
appRouter.on('route:back', function() {
    history.go(-2);
});
```

Going back by -2 is needed to cancel out the `#back` route.